# One stripped post mount on suspension fork

Tags: brakes, mechanical, repair, hydraulic-disc-brake

I have a suspension fork, which has a stripped lower post mount, i.e. the bolt used to attach the brake caliper doesn't grip the post. Before anyone asks - yes, it is the correct size bolt, as the upper post is fine. Would it be possible to use something like a heli-coil insert to repair the thread or would you consider this unsafe ? FYI I am running a 160mm disc up front, and only do XC/Trail riding - so nothing too mental :-)..Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 2):

You might consider tapping this thread back out if you have a decent tap-and-die set.  Otherwise, a heli-coil should work for this application.  I would be more concerned with a heli-coil if you were using it on a post-bolt that would experience tensile stress--that is, "pull-out" force.  This bolt will be under mostly shear-stress, which means that the majority of the strength will be derived from the body of the post rather than from the threads.

I'm not an engineer--engineers, please correct me--but this is what my thinking is when I fix a broken piece of metal in a situation like yours.

If you are a little paranoid, you might goop the bolt threads with some JB Weld before threading them into the heli-coil.  This will add a little tensile strength and piece of mind, but should be pretty easy to break out with a breaker-bar if and when you choose to remove the part.

Note also that, in my experience, any use of a heli-coil or JB weld has the potential to be an "ultimate" fix.  That is, once it's *fixed*... it's *fixed* for all practical purposes and subject to failure if "fixed" again in the same place.  I might do this to my 90's Rockhopper, but I don't suggest it for your 2011 Santa Cruz Blur that you plan to change everything out on next season.

*Short answer:*  With the sort of riding you are suggesting, I would do the fix you are suggesting on my beater mountain bike.  On my high-end down-hill ride... I would take it to a frame builder and have the post replaced.